# How to fix Odata with C# WebAPI .NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I can retrieve all of the data but looks like OData is not working
I'm using EFCore Entity Framework Web API. 
This is my reference for OData https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCDWUBOJ5FU

Updated Model below

Return should be

```
[
    {
        "name":"FakeHelmet"
    },
    {
        "name":"OriginalHelmet"
    },
    {
        "name":"ClassAHelmet"
    }
]
```

This is my Code.

Controller :

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var models = await service.Filter();
    return Ok(models);
}
```

Service

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<HelmetDto>> Filter()
{
    var models = repo.GetQueryableTest<Helmet>();
    return models.Select(x => SimpleMapper.Map(x, new HelmetDto()));
}
```

Repository

```cs
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryableTest<TEntity>()
where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();
    return query;
}
```

I  also added this in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddOData();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
             routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();        
             routeBuilder.
               Count().
               Filter().
               OrderBy().
               Expand().
               Select().
               MaxTop(null);
         });
}
```

This is my Model

```
public class Helmet
{
    public Helmet()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public String Type { get; set; }
}
```

the request would be `localhost:5002/api/Helmet?$select=name`

The `OData` that I created is not working. Hoping for an answer. 
This is my reference for OData https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCDWUBOJ5FU

Return should be

```
[
    {
        "name":"FakeHelmet"
    },
    {
        "name":"OriginalHelmet"
    },
    {
        "name":"ClassAHelmet"
    }
]
```

Comment: please include your Helmet model

Comment: @metal see updated code above

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't add routes mapping for OData Service:

**Approach 1:**

Add a `[Route("api/[controller]")]` annotation for your `HelmetController`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public partial class HelmetController: ControllerBase
{

}
```

**Approach 2**

configure a particular OData routes :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
         routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "odata",
            "api",
            GetEdmModel(),
            new DefaultODataBatchHandler()
         );
         routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();        
         routeBuilder.
           Count().
           Filter().
           OrderBy().
           Expand().
           Select().
           MaxTop(null);
         routeBuilder.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
         );
     });
}
```

This will make the `OData` work on route that starts with `/api`.

Here the `GetEdmModel()` method is where you setup the EDM model:

```cs
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Helmet>("Helmet")
        .EntityType.Filter().Count().Expand().OrderBy().Page().Select();
}
```

Note in both situation your controller name should be `HelmetController` instead of `HelmetsController` because you're configuring the Model name as `Helmet` instead of `Helmets`.

Finally, you can query the `Helmet` as below :

```
/api/Helmet?$select=name
```

Comment: @DanilIshutin But it works fine for me. What do you get when you access `/api/Helmet?$select=name`?

Comment: ```private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Helmet>("Helmet")
        .EntityType.Filter().Count().Expand().OrderBy().Page().Select();
}``` This one needs a return

Comment: ```routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(
      "odata",
      "api",
      GetEdmModel(),
      new DefaultODataBatchHandler()
      );``` this one is error too. I got a red line in new DefaultODataBatchHandler()

Comment: @DanilIshutin 1. Please add a `return builder.GetEdmModel();` for the `GetEdmModel()` method. Sorry, I didn't mention that.  2. Did you forget to add `using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Batch;` ?

Comment: @DanilIshutin If you still can't make it, could you please share us with your demo online if possible?

Comment: what is the return for this?private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
  {
   ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
   builder.EntitySet<Helmet>("Helmet")
    .EntityType.Filter().Count().Expand().OrderBy().Page().Select();
  }

Comment: @DanilIshutin `return builder.GetEdmModel();`

Comment: still not working. I followed all of it and still OData doesnt work. It will return all the data in the table when using this url : /api/Helmet?$select=name

Comment: @DanilIshutin Could you please upload your complete project online if it is not a commercial project? Or I could upload my demo that works for your reference.

Comment: Sorry man. Cant upload this one. Some data in here is confidential

Comment: This are my reference 1. https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/OData-Query-Options and this 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCDWUBOJ5FU

Comment: @DanilIshutin I guess there's something wrong with the part you didn't mention. See [my working demo]  (https://send.firefox.com/download/952437c7ec1afe00/#7GBtPUGIfhroqnJNiH3NyQ)